# groovy generic fluent builder

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, dsl

I'd like to create a simple wrapper, which would allow calling objects methods as a fluent interface. I've been thinking about rewriting methods of a class upon creation, but this doesn't seem to work. Is this possible in some way with groovy metaprograming?

I have this kind of code snippet so far:

```
class FluentWrapper {

    def delegate

    FluentWrapper(wrapped) {
        delegate = wrapped

        delegate.class.getMethods().each { method ->
            def name = method.getName()
            FluentWrapper.metaClass."$name" = { Object[] varArgs ->
                method.invoke(wrapped, name, varArgs)
                return this
            }
        }
    }

    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        def method = delegate.getClass().getDeclaredMethods().find { it.match(name) }
        if(method) {

            method.invoke(delegate,name, args)
            return FluentWrapper(delegate)
        }
        else throw new MissingMethodException(name, delegate, args)
    }

}
```

Assuming example Java class:

```
class Person {
    void setAge()
    void setName()
}
```

I'd like to be able to execute the following piece of code:

```
def wrappedPerson = new FluentWrapper(new Person())
wrappedPerson.setAge().setName()
```

I'm using Groovy 1.6.7 for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all Groovy, and I'm using 1.8.6 (the current latest), but given this Person Class:

```
class Person {
  int age
  String name

  public void setAge( int age ) { this.age = age }
  public void setName( String name ) { this.name = name }
  public String toString() { "$name $age" }
}
```

And this FluentWrapper class:

```
class FluentWrapper {

  def delegate

  FluentWrapper(wrapped) {
    delegate = wrapped
  }

  def methodMissing(String name, args) {
    def method = delegate.getClass().declaredMethods.find { it.name == name }
    if(method) {
      method.invoke( delegate, args )
      return this
    }
    else throw new MissingMethodException(name, delegate, args)
  }
}
```

Then, you should be able to do:

```
def wrappedPerson = new FluentWrapper(new Person())

Person person = wrappedPerson.setAge( 85 ).setName( 'tim' ).delegate
```

And `person` should have the age and name specified

Comment: Great, so using newer version is just what I should have done :) I'll test this on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

I find @tim_yates' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9840048/606885) nice, but you couldn't access `delegate` methods' return values (something one usually likes doing, even for Builders in the case of `build()` :)

Moreover, if this wasn't intended for a Builder but for an object with a chainable interface (like that of jQuery wrapped objects in JS), it would be a serious issue.

So I'd put the wrapper like this:

```
class FluentWrapper {

  def delegate

  FluentWrapper(wrapped) {
    delegate = wrapped
  }

  def methodMissing(String name, args) {
    def method = delegate.getClass().declaredMethods.find { it.name == name }
    if(method) {
      def result = method.invoke(delegate, args)
      return result != null ? result : this
    }
    else throw new MissingMethodException(name, delegate, args)
  }
}
```

Note the elvis operator is unsuitable since a falsy value would never get returned.

Of course, it's up to the invoker to know wether a method is chainable or not, but that could be overcome with method annotations if neccesary.

Comment: This is in fact better solution in case of classical fluent builder approach. However I'd not do this since I want to execute multiple functions without worrying too much about what's coming out of the wrapped object. Perhaps it would be nice to merge those approaches and add some constructor value that would allow to decide which behaviour is intended for this specific wrapper.